# Average of Multiple columns in dplyr getting error "must resolve to integer column positions, not a list"

Tags: r, dplyr

```
 gene   HSC_7256.bam HSC_6792.bam HSC_7653.bam   HSC_5852
```

My data frame looks like this i can do that in a normal way such as take out the columns make another data frame average it ,but i want to do that in dplyr and im having a hard time I not sure what is the problem

I doing something like this

```
HSC<- EPIGENETIC_FACTOR_SEQMONK %>%
    select(EPIGENETIC_FACTOR_SEQMONK,gene)
```

I get this error

> Error: `EPIGENETIC_FACTOR_SEQMONK` must resolve to integer column positions, not a list

So i have to do this take out all the HSC sample average them

Anyone suggest what am i doing it incorrectly ?that would be helpful

Comment: Is `EPIGENETIC_FACTOR_SEQMONK` the name of a column in your data frame? If not, you cannot `select` it.

Comment: no thats the name of my data frame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%>%` function pulls whatever is to the left of it into the first position of the following function. If your data frame is `EPIGENETIC_FACTOR_SEQMONK`, then these two statements are equivalent:

```
HSC <- EPIGENETIC_FACTOR_SEQMONK %>%
   select(gene)

HSC <- select(EPIGENETIC_FACTOR_SEQMONK, gene)
```

In the first, we are passing `EPIGENETIC_FACTOR_SEQMONK` into `select` using `%>%`, which is generally used in `dplyr` chains as the first argument in `dplyr` functions is a data frame.

Comment: Thank you now i can select my desired column , so how can I pass it and take average of the my columns ?i have to use the mutate function ?

Comment: You probably want `summarize`. Take a look at the `dplyr` documentation and vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html